# Bash will not execute system command in Perl script

Tags: bash, perl

Need a Bash file to run a perl script.

---

This is the Perl file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;


system "fastacmd -s $Q -d $NewQuery -o ./gifiles/$Q.$NewQuery.txt";
```

I have left alot out to avoid complications when understanding this script. Before using a bash command, the script did work with the variables defined.

---

Here is the Bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

#$ -o $HOME/xREPLaunch_$JOB_ID.out

#$ -e $HOME/xREPLaunch_$JOB_ID.err

cd $HOME/Labwork/Dbfiles/results

#$ -cwd

perl xREPredoTop.pl
```

---

For some reason I keep getting this error

```
Can't exec "fastacmd": No such file or directory at xREPredoTop.pl line 78, <IN> line 1.
```

Really confused to why this is not working.

Comment: That's the perl script indicating that it cannot find "fastacmd". The output of the shell command `which fastacmd` might be handy, or to inspect what `$ENV{PATH}` contains in the perl script, to see what directories it is looking for things in.

Comment: Post the output of `echo "$PATH"` and of `ls -l /path/to/fastacmd` (with the right path to the script).

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities I can think of:

The usual one is that you are running the bash script from something like cron, where your user profile script hasn't run and set up $PATH.  In this case you can specify

```
system "/path/to/fastacmd ...
```

within the perl script so that it doesn't depend on the path, or you can set the

```
$ENV{PATH}= "/my/custom/paths:$ENV{PATH}";
```

inside the perl script, or you can fix the path in the bash script by loading your profile scripts:

```
source /etc/profile;
source ~/.profile;
source ~/.bash_profile;
```

But the other possibility is that `#!/usr/bin/perl` declared in your script is not the same perl as in your PATH.  You can check this by saying

```
which perl
```

For example, if you say `./xREPredoTop.pl` it becomes

```
/usr/bin/perl -w ./xREPredoTop.pl
```

but if you say `perl ./xREPredoTop.pl` it could become

```
/usr/local/bin/perl ./xREPredoTop.pl
```

and that one could be configured differently in some way that it changes the path.